# Add list with column names to a list without lose names in R

Tags: r

I want to add list `l1` with column names `a1.attr1`, `a1.attr2` to another list `l` without to lose column names. For example:

```
> l<-list()
> l1<-list(a1.attr1=1,a1.attr2=2)
> l1
$a1.attr1
[1] 1

$a1.attr2
[1] 2
```

now If I do:

```
>l[1]<-l1
>names(l)[1]<-"a1"
```

I will not have `l` as a list with one column of name `a1` whose value is a two-column list with names `a1.attr1`and `a2.attr2` and values 1 and 2, as you can see:

```
> l
$a1
[1] 1
```

the inner column names are lost and the inner list is truncated.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this what you want? `l[[1]] <- l1`?

Comment: Yes, but why this happens like this?

Comment: Check this link https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html. I added an answer to my comment, consider accepting the answer if it solves your question.

Comment: Yes I will accept.. I miss only the explanation, it is due to coercion?

Comment: `[` will only return a list, while `[[` will return the components of the list (when applied to one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try instead:

```
  l[[1]] <- l1
```

For further information, see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.data.frame.html).